# What is the "half black screen" in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

Sometime my iPhone shows half of a black screen, which comes from the top and happens after touching the home button. 
Does anyone has an idea what this is and how to reproduce it ?

Comment: Does it happen by 'touching' the home button or double tapping it?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, it's actually part of my question ;)

Comment: If you are concerned about the screen shifting down, with top half rendered black, this is a feature called [Reachability](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-reachability-on-iphone-6-6-plus/)

Comment: @vin Thanks, you should post this as an answer. Will validate...

Comment: I believe this has already been asked and answered before(although I am unable to find the original). It would be better if someone with 'privileges' marks this as a dup.